# Android hardware codec in kindle fire hdx not working

Tags: android, hardware, codec, kindle-fire

I am working on hardware codec for kindle fire hdx. I am not able get encoded stream, for first frame I got input and output buffer index postive and encoded length,

for second frame I got only input buffer index positive and failed to get output buffer index always. If I play the encoded stream I am getting black window.

Please If any one works on it help me.